# Exporting the object of the class vs exporting the singleton class. Javascript

Tags: javascript, singleton

Is there any difference between the following approaches? I am fond of the second approach as it is more clear but I am seeing Approach 1 also on the internet. So wondering if there any benefit of one approach over other.

### Approach 1

**Singleton.ts**

```
class Singleton {
    private static _instance: Singleton | null = null
    
    private constructor() {}
    
    public static getInstance() {
        if (!Singleton._instance) {
            Singleton._instance = new Singleton()
        }
        return Singleton._instance
    }
    
    public doSomeWork() {}
}


export default Singleton
```

**test1.ts**

```
import Singleton from './Singleton'

Singleton.getInstance().doSomeWork()
```

**test2.ts**

```
import Singleton from './Singleton'

Singleton.getInstance().doSomeWork()
```

### Approach 2

**Singleton.ts**

```
class Singleton {
    constructor() {
        
    }    
    
    public doSomeWork() {}
}


export default new Singleton()
```

**test1.ts**

```
import singleton from './Singleton'

singleton.doSomeWork()
```

**test2.ts**

```
import singleton from './Singleton'

singleton.doSomeWork()
```

Answer (score 0):

Second one is preferable I think. First one actually allows instantiating multiple times.